# Using Heroku to db:pull a new database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, pull

I am trying to learn how to push and pull databases using Heroku's system, I just have a clarifying question.

My existing development database is called `project_dev` but I want to create a new database. I entered in the following command:

```
heroku db:pull mysql://root:mydbpassword@localhost/20110302heroku
```

I have a database.yml file that includes my development, test, and production dbs, and I got this response from Heroku:

```
Auto-detected local database: mysql://root:mydbpassword@localhost/project_dev?encoding=utf8
```

Does this mean I have to manually create a new database first if I want to pull from Heroku? Does it mean that I cannot pull at all unless the db is explicitly defined in my database.yml file?

Any pointers would be really helpful. I had a look around on Google, Heroku and SO, but I didn't find the answers I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll have to first create the new local database but you don't have to declare it in your database.yml file.

When I run `heroku db:pull mysql://root:mydbpassword@localhost/newdb` it correctly imports into the `newdb` database. I'm not sure why it auto-detects your local dev database. Do you use the latest heroku and taps gems?

Comment: I haven't created the database 20110302heroku yet. Perhaps taps isn't finding the database I specified so it then looks to database.yml as a backup source? I'll try creating the database first and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @sscirrus: with taps 0.3.17 and heroku 1.18.0, when I run "heroku db:pull" it first says "Warning: Data in the database 'mysql://root:mydbpassword@localhost/newdb' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable." and then asks for confirmation and then aborts if the database does not exist. Which versions of taps and heroku do you use?

Comment: I just updated to taps 0.3.17 and heroku 1.18.2. I also created a new local database called `20110303heroku` and I tried `heroku db:pull mysql://root:mydbpassword@localhost/20110303heroku`, but it is still defaulting to my other database: `project_dev`. What do I have to do to get it to stop assuming I always want to affect project_dev?

Comment: @sscirrus: well I'm sorry I don't know why it behaves like this for you :( might be worth contacting the Heroku support or fill a ticket in the Heroku gem issue tracker: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues Let us know if you get a solution

Comment: Thanks for all your help my friend. +1 for the effort.